# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Running Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer I receive the following error - any ideas/hints:

```
[2017-11-08 16:35:42.854] [ERROR] Helper - Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: write EPROTO 140490697390144:error:1411713E:SSL routines:ssl_check_srvr_ecc_cert_and_alg:ecc cert n
ot for signing:ssl_lib.c:2512:
140490697390144:error:14082130:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:bad ecc cert:s3_clnt.c:3546:
]
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/osboxes/dev/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClientImpl.js:711:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:343:10)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:361:5)
    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:90:5)
    at fireErrorCallbacks (net.js:467:13)
[2017-11-08 16:35:42.854] [DEBUG] Helper - admin failed to register
[2017-11-08 16:35:42.854] [ERROR] Helper - admin enrollment failed
[2017-11-08 16:35:42.854] [ERROR] Query - Error: Missing userContext parameter
    at new TransactionID (/home/osboxes/dev/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/TransactionID.js:43:10)
    at Channel.queryBlock (/home/osboxes/dev/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:905:14)
    at helper.getRegisteredUsers.then (/home/osboxes/dev/fabric-samples/blockchain-explorer/app/query.js:91:18)
(node:12336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Cannot save null userContext.
(node:12336) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined
```

Comment: Hey, I edited your title to "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of the blockchain-explorer, the error is only mentioned once here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/863278adb9d8ca11ea5063ee9f9600a625058b4d/app/platform/fabric/gateway/FabricGateway.js#L226

Given the exception states `ecc cert not for signing` followed by `bad ecc cert` I'd imagine you're attempting to use use a secure protocol (https/grpcs) where perhaps you haven't set up the relevant SSL certificates?

If you see the output of this line in the (blockchain-explorer) logs:

```
    logger.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> enrollment ', enrollment);
```

I suspect problem is within the `ca.enroll()` which relied on the URL to the CA server being accessible and correct (verify the host and port are open for connections from the machine your error occurred on - hint `nc -zv HOST PORT` to check its open nc is the netcat command).

Hopefully this will get you some way to where you need to be. Look at the source code further - you should find some hints there.